# Android set Automatically auto_fit for Grid View

Tags: android

in application i'm setting `numColumns` to `auto_fit`. when phone `orientation` is `portrait`, GridView hase 2 column and after rotate phone to `landscape` GridView has 2 column and don't set automatically change to more than 2 column.

GridView Layout:

```
<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"></GridView>
```

and GridView column layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10px"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_inbox"
                android:layout_gravity="center"></ImageView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/grid_item_label"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5px"
                android:text="ffffffffffffff"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:gravity="center"></TextView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Auto-Fit is applicable only in the case where columns have fixed width. You need to specify a fixed width for your columns. Add this to your GridView:

```
android:columnWidth="100dp"
```

The following excerpt is taken from the source code of `GridView's` `determineColumns` method:

```
if (mRequestedNumColumns == AUTO_FIT) {
        if (requestedColumnWidth > 0) {
            mNumColumns = (availableSpace + requestedHorizontalSpacing) /
                    (requestedColumnWidth + requestedHorizontalSpacing);
        } else {
            mNumColumns = 2;
        }
}
```

Unless your requestedColumnWidth > 0, you always get 2 columns, which is the observation in your case.

Comment: Since you have already set num of columns to auto-fit, android will automatically fit as many columns as possible within the current screen width space keeping 100dp minimum width in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Create Landscape Layout and configure it to fit more than 2 columns